# MVC3: Route with same name as directory

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, routes

I have an ASP.NET MVC Route URL set to "/Services" which points to a controller action, but there is also a directory that contains my C# Services classes called "Services" which users cannot navigate to. This is causing issues with my route. It throws the following error:

```
HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.
```

Does anyone know how to overcome this?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would probably be best to not have this sort of clash but you can disable that feature by setting the [RouteExistingFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routecollection.routeexistingfiles.aspx) property on RouteCollection.

Comment: Thanks, how do I avoid such clashes when it is a CMS and the end user can choose their own route values?

Comment: Also, can you elaborate on why those sort of clashes should be avoided?

Comment: Marking this as answer for the `RouteExistingFiles property on RouteCollection` part. Still unsure about the rest.

Comment: I'd only avoid the clash in order to keep life simple. If you give users total freedom to choose route values how do you avoid clashes?

Comment: That's what I'm saying, you can't. And if you have to write logic to prevent clashes as well as have to maintain a list of folders that are to be avoided, then I think that goes against 'keeping life simple'. The `RouteExistingFiles` property keeps life simple in my mind. Thanks